# Mirror SVG elements around their own axis

Tags: svg, mirror

I'd like to mirror arbitrary SVG elements programmatically in place. That means they should remain in their current position, but get mirrored.

I know that I can mirror elements by using `scale(1, -1)` and then translate them. 
But the question is: How do I know the amount to translate?

I thought I could calculate the amount by adding the height of the element and twice the distance of the element to the 0-axis.

This works for example with this:

```
<polyline id="line1" stroke="green" stroke-width="1" fill="none"
          points="
                  10, 10           
                  20, 10    20, 20    30, 20    30, 10
                  40, 10    40, 30    50, 30    50, 10
                  60, 10    60, 40    70, 40    70, 10
                  80, 10    80, 50    90, 50    90, 10
                 100, 10   100, 60   110, 60   110, 10
                 "
          transform="scale(1, -1) translate(0, -70)"
/>
```

The height of the element is 50, the distance to the 0-axis is 10, so the distance is `50 + 2 * 10 = 70`.

However, this means the calculation differs with the type of the element (line, polyline, rect, g) and whether the object is already translated.

Is there a generic way to mirror SVG elements in place?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the transform operations you have to apply will depend on all those factors you pointed out.  There is no simple 'generic' way that will work in every instance.  You will need to work it out on a case by case basis.

The `getBBox()` method gives the bounding box of the element *after* the application of any `transform` attribute.  From that you can determine the axis of reflection (ie. centre axis) and hence the transform operations required.

Answer (score 0):

That case in just another application of the »Scale around Point« problem (the same as rotate around point, too). As @BigBadaboom pointed out, you need to use the bounding Box of the element. And from there you need to do three steps:

First move/translate the object so that the point you would like to scale the Object around lies in the origin ((0,0)),

Second: scale,

third: move/translate it back by the negative vector from step one.

You can pre calculate the transform matrix you need to apply by multiplying all the matrices from step one to three mentioned above.

Please note that `getBBox()` will give you the bounding box in local coordinates, so if the element resides in a group which already has a transformation applied the coordinates are relative to this group.

`getBoundingClientRect()` will deliver values in absolute coordinates.

That is important since you need to decide whether to perform your calculation in absolute or local space. Even if it is tempting to use local space I re common to use the absolute space, since it will work for each element, even it is deeply nested in the DOM with a bunch of transformation already applied.

`getTransformToElement()` will be you friend to compute the absolute Transformation of any element.

So if if you calculate the needed transform for the element in absolute space, you just need to apply a »change of basis« to this transformation, to bring it back into local space.

All these affine Transformations may look a bit complicated at the first glance, but it is worth to get the math behind it, once learned scale, rotation, shear and chained transformations (arround points, too) wont be a problem any longer.

Good Luck!